# Fetch in JS adds automatically the current page url, how to remove it

Tags: javascript, fetch

So im trying to make a fetch request like this:

```
var url = "";
const domain = window.location.host;

if (sort === "all")  {
    url = domain + "/api/post-list/all";
}
else {
    url = domain + "/api/post-list/" + sort;
}

fetch(url)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(posts => {
  
  console.log(posts);
  posts.forEach(post => update_posts(post, sort));

});
```

problem is, fetch automatically adds the current page's url, but i dont need that, so it ends up requesting like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/127.0.0.1:8000/api/post-list/enn
```

when it should be just this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/post-list/enn`.

or from this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/127.0.0.1:8000/api/post-list/all` to this  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/post-list/all`

Is there a way?

Comment: you don't the domain at all it will always pick it if you leave it relative, it's redundant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
const domain = window.location.origin
```

Comment: Oh wow, so the http in front did the trick, thank you! (Will accept ur answer in a few mins)

Comment: Someone else faced this issue? I can't seem to understand the answer

Answer (score 1):

Delete the domain it s not needed as per your example

```
var url = "";


if (sort === "all")  {
    url = "/api/post-list/all";
}
else {
    url = "/api/post-list/" + sort;
}

fetch(url)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(posts => {
  
  console.log(posts);
  posts.forEach(post => update_posts(post, sort));

});
```

Comment: When im at a user's profile, the link will be domain/profile/username  & fetch will request domain/profile/api/post-list/username, which doesnt match my api url. Thats why i decided to change the whole link